# Javascript - Load an image onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, captcha

OK, I'm actually calling some java middleware that returns a captcha image. The captcha image loads in the page on page load simply with:

```
<a href="#" id="ci"><img id="stickyImg" src="stickyImg" /></a>
```

I want to reload the captcha image onclick of the current captcha image. I've tried a few things but am not getting anything working.

By "tried a few things" I mean I have tried:

```
$("#ci").click(function(){

        $("#stickyImg").load('stickyImg');

        return false;
    });
```

which indeed loads the image but it does it by placing the raw binary image data inside the image tag so I get:

`<img src="stickyImg"><img xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">pngbinarygibberishsymbols</img>`

Hmmm... maybe I need to specify putting the image into the src attribute? Perhaps? What do you all think?

---

**EDIT:**

Ugh! Putting the response into my img src results in:

```
<img src="    * captcha image�PNG  ��� IHDR�������Ketc, etc">
```

The raw binary data being output. What the heck?

---

**SOLUTION:**

The solution comes from another, similar, post I made on this. You can [read about it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061646/captcha-image-coming-back-a-binary-data-how-to-display-this/4061774#4061774)

In the end the (*edited thanks to Lee) code that works looks like:

```
$("#ci").click(function(){

        $("#stickyImg").attr('src', 'stickyImg?' + (new Date().getTime())); 
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: where does your image located?? are you giving absolute path or some url like http://myimages.com/images/image.jpg

Comment: No absolute path. It's a java thing. The page load triggers "stickyImg" which summons the image from the java middleware that I am tied into.

Comment: in your solution, the call to `load('stickyImg')` is unnecessary and could cause problems.  you want just:  `$("#stickyImg").attr('src','stickyImg?'+(new Date().getTime()))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it would be helpful if you would post a more complete example including the markup that embeds your image in the initial document; but making a few reasonable assumptions, I think you just need something like the following...

assuming that your markup is something like:

```
<div id="ci">
  <img src="/stickyImage" />
</div>
```

then the following JS should do the trick:

```
$("#ci").click(function(){

    $("img",this).remove();
    $(this).html('<img src="/stickyImage" />');

    return false;
});
```

good luck.

---

[edit]  If you're using this code to load an image that's generated dynamically on your server (or that may change periodically, for some reason), then you'll also want to be sure that you properly account for the browser's tendency to cache data that it believes to be static.  There are two way that this is commonly accomplished (either will work):

1) ensure that the url is always different every time the image is loaded.  You can do this easily, by just appending a random number to the query string portion of the image url.  So, in the above example, `$(this).html('<img src="/stickyImage" />')`, would become `$(this).html('<img src="/stickyImage?"+(new Date().getTime()) />')`.  (This is essentially identical to the approach that the OP ultimately settled on -- see OP's edits above).

2) ensure that the server returns the image data, including the proper HTTP headers in the response to indicate that the image is dynamic and shouldn't be cached.  You can see [more details about how to send no-cache headers on this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407).

Here's how you would set the needed headers from within a Java servlet:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
```

Option #2 is perhaps the more "technically correct" way to address the caching issue, but as I said above - either will work, and option#1 is a very reliable approach that is often substantially easier than option #2.

All this being said - the caching issue is a separate issue from the original question that was asked here.  The original question involved display of binary blobs inline in the HTML. That problem resulted from the incorrect use of the jquery `load()` function. The OP settled on an approach that uses the `attr()` function to set the `src` attribute.  The approach I've shown involves creating a new `img` element, and removing the old element.  Either of these approaches will work, but the `load()` function will not work for this purpose.

Comment: I did include the complete markup. All I have in the page is <img src="stickyImg" /> That's all of the html markup. Nothing else. That causes a java servelet, mapped to the simplecaptcha package, to generate the captcha image and insert it.

Comment: That doesn't work, by the way. It causes the same thing I show in the updated edit in my comment... outputting a string of binary data.

Comment: @rg88 - Yes, you *added* your markup in edit #3 of your post--thank you for that.  If your markup contains only the image as you've shown it, then how do your jquery selectors work at all?  where is `#ci`? and `#stickyImage`?

Comment: @rg88 - can you describe more precisely what is happening when you say "outputting a string of binary data"?  Is it (as you've shown above) putting the binary junk inside the src attribute of the html markup (like this:  `<img src="binary junk here" />`)?  Or is it showing binary junk rendered in the browser instead of the image?

Comment: Ahhh... I see. I left out the link wrapping the code and the id on stickyImg because I figured it didn't really matter to my specific question. I should have been more complete. I have added it above. I also added the solution to this problem (and accepted your suggestion for the time you put in... the solution turned out to be something else but you can read that in my edited post)

Comment: @rg88 - thanks for accepting the answer.  It *is* actually a correct solution to this problem.  I can see no way that you actually tried my complete suggestion before you determined that it didn't work.  My example would have the same effect as the solution you posted above.  In any case, it *does not* result in putting raw binary data into the src attribute.  best of luck.

Comment: @Lee - I did try this and it simply does not work. The captcha image does not change unless you change the image path by adding something to the query string as described in the solution I linked to in my question. Your method results in the same image being presented over and over. Using your method, if I add some random data to an image query string it will work but without it... no change.

Comment: @rg88 - Yes, this happens because the browser caches the image. It does so because your server isn't sending no-cache headers for that image data. Dynamic data should always come with no-cache headers [see this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers) for details & how-to.  Of course, this is all a separate issue from your original question, which involved incorrect use of the [jquery load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/). That's the cause of the binary "blobs" you were seeing. And that's what I addressed in my answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

this is a good post:
http://emilsblog.lerch.org/2009/07/javascript-hacks-using-xhr-to-load.html

i referenced here:
[How do I load binary image data using Javascript and XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095102/how-do-i-load-binary-image-data-using-javascript-and-xmlhttprequest)