# Convert image to base64

Tags: javascript, base64

I'm trying to convert an image into base64 using javascript, however if I request the URL with jquery, and encode with javascript, the results are different than what I receive from here (http://www.scalora.org/projects/uriencoder/) when saving and uploading the image..

Is there any reason for this?

I'm just using $.get and base64 encoding function data()

Comment: What happens if you drop the image into [Hashify](http://hashify.me/). Does the Base64 string in the resulting data URI match either of the strings you generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095102/how-do-i-load-binary-image-data-using-javascript-and-xmlhttprequest) covers this exact topic and has a solution that works for IE and Firefox.  The short answer is that XHR really isn't designed for binary data and the data gets corrupted or truncated when converted to a string for `XHR.responseText`.

It would be best to Base 64 encode on the server side.