# httprequest and binary data in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, binary-data, responsetext

Still struggling after lots of tries to read the response of a httprequest that is a binary datastream which will represent an jpg image.

edit: the whole thing

```
xmlhttp = false;
        /*@cc_on@*/
        /*@if (@_jscript_version >= 5)
        // JScript gives us Conditional compilation, we can cope with old IE versions.
        // and security blocked creation of the objects.
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (E) {
                xmlhttp = false;
            }
        }
        @end@*/
        if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
            try {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } catch (e) {
                xmlhttp = false;
            }
        }
        if (!xmlhttp && window.createRequest) {
            try {
                xmlhttp = window.createRequest();
            } catch (e) {
                xmlhttp = false;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, true);  
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {

                var headers = xmlhttp.getAllResponseHeaders(); 
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.send(null);
```

I am using IE8, and no HTML 5 (also tried in FF12)
so i always end up with errors with something like

```
xhr.overrideMimeType('text\/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
```

or

```
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
```

even copying into a variable won´t work

```
var body = xhr.response; //.responseText , .responseBody
```

any ideas whats wrong or wwhat i could try?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to accomplish? Can your server do b64 encoding?

Comment: no its an embedded device and the company won´t change their interface sadly

Comment: But then how are you supposed to use the binary data on the script side?

Comment: the plan is to create the image out of the images data stream

Comment: [You might want to look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095102/how-do-i-load-binary-image-data-using-javascript-and-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: @wrock thx i already knew about this link, but it will include vbscript which i tried to avoid, but i will try the solution until something else is found

Answer (score 1):

I made [this example](http://exifdemo.staticloud.com/) to read binary JPEG on client-side and parse EXIF data. It uses [BinFileReader.js](http://nagoon97.wordpress.com/reading-binary-files-using-ajax) which makes it really easy to deal with binary data, cross-browser. [Here is the whole thing in a zip file](http://exifdemo.staticloud.com/exif_demo.zip), including a node-based webserver (run with node server.js) I included a [web-worker example](http://exifdemo.staticloud.com/worker.html), also.

If you are just making an image out of binary stream, why not just add `<img src="blah" />` to your DOM?

```
$('body').append('<img src="' + URL + '"/>');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?