# How can I display a 'Reload' symbol in HTML without loading an image via HTTP?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, unicode

I would like to display a 'refresh' symbol in an HTML/JavaScript app I'm creating, but I do not want to make any HTTP requests to load an image. How can I do this reliably across all major browsers?

The closest Unicode value I could find is: ↺ (`&#8634;`), but the arrow is pointing the wrong way.

Is there another Unicode value that works?

Is there a Webdings font that works? (They don't usually work in Opera and Firefox.)

Is there a way to create an image in JavaScript using a *base64 image source* provided by a String from that JS?

EDIT:

The reason for this is NOT overhead.  The app being created must be self-contained in a single javascript file, without any other dependencies.  It is a development utility that can be added to any project, without the need for a network.

Comment: Has this got to run on [Lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser)) or something?! I'm intrigued as to why an image is not appropriate. However, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095102/how-do-i-load-binary-image-data-using-javascript-and-xmlhttprequest) discusses loading an image from binary using JS - maybe that will help?

Comment: Why not use the words "Refresh"? Think about it, does it have to be a symbol to tell the user that it does a refresh?

Comment: Did you consider drawing the pciture using Canvas paint or SVG ?

Comment: @Joseph:  Steve B.  I didn't consider that.  But that would eliminate many browsers, would it not?

Comment: What the heck does "wrong way" mean? Does reloading have a physical orientation in space? Does it matter if the client machine uses big or little endian memory access?  &#8634; is showing what is conventionally a "positive rotation" in mathematics. According to the "right hand rule", if we curl our fingers in the direction of rotation, the thumb points backwards, like hailing a cab. This indicates "we are yanking a new copy of the page out of the screen": reload!

Comment: ⭯ ⭮ ↺ ↻ ⟲ ⟳ 

Comment: @DanDascalescu how can those icons be added to a web page - is there an HTML unicode for them?

Comment: @DanRoberts: just paste them.

Comment: @DanDascalescu I mean into an HTML web page. Special characters need to be encoded e.g. `&reg;`

Comment: @DanRoberts: [no they don't](https://codepen.io/dandv/pen/MWKXdpz)! It's a myth. Only [*extremely few*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381974/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-in-html) characters *need* to be be encoded, depending on where they appear. The most important is `&lt;`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the browser supports loading image data from a Base64 string, you can use `img` and set its `src` to the following format:

```
data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>
```

Example:

```js
var img = document.getElementById("yourImage");
img.src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/f3//Ub//ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcppV0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g77ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNgYPj/gAwXEQA7";
```

```html
<img id="yourImage" />
```

Comment: Just don't forget that cause an overhead compared to a file loaded using `<img src='**'>`. This will include, in B64 format the whole picture (2,5 times heavier if I'm right). And this will be reloaded everytime the page is rendered, and not once (with cache) when a static picture is served. This can be a valid solution though, if the picture is small (probably the case here), and if the overead is acceptable. (gziping or deflating the http channel can also help)

Comment: @SteveB: ”2,5 times heavier if I'm right” — I think that depends on the image, and on the effect of gzip compression on the file that the base64-encoded string is included in.

Comment: @SteveB: “this will be reloaded everytime the page is rendered, and not once (with cache) when a static picture is served” — although not if the file that contains the base64-encoded string is cached.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: it's possible, but it requires a full javascript loading of dynamic content (if not the refresh action would make no sense). But it's possible

Comment: @SteveB: well, the base64-encoded string might be contained in an external JavaScript file that’s cached, which wouldn’t (necessarily) be re-downloaded just because the HTML page was.

Comment: @David: the OP did specifically ask about a JavaScript plus data-uri solution.

Comment: @fardjad: Thanks for the fiddle.  That puts this answer at the top of the list.  If no one has a better (more cross-browser) solution soon,  I'll accept this as the best answer.

Answer (score 139):

If you find the character `&#8635;` (↻), i.e. U+21BB CLOCKWISE OPEN CIRCLE ARROW, acceptable for your needs (its arrow might not be placed the same way as in common reload icons), then you can use it rather safely:

```css
.reload {
  font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode
}
```

```html
<span class=reload>&#x21bb;</span>
```

The Lucida Sans Unicode font contains the symbol, and it is available in virtually any Windows system you can find these days. According to [MS info](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1263), it was included even in Windows 98 (and Windows 95 plus).

Systems other than Windows can reasonably be expected to have the symbol in *some* font and to have browsers that know how to pick it up from some of them. And [fonts containing it](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/21bb/fontsupport.htm) have rather similar shapes for it. (But if the symbol needs to match stylistically the text of your document, you need to study the situation in more detail and try to make sure that all fonts in your font list, or “font stack”, contain it.)

Comment: @dpd, what is your jsfiddle supposed to demonstrate? It declares Arial, which does not contain U+21BB, so what you get is your browser’s default font or fallback font or, in some old browsers, a failure.

Answer (score 70):

## Unicode Character

There are at least two Unicode characters that might serve as *Refresh* or *Reload* icons:

- CLOCKWISE GAPPED CIRCLE ARROW
  U+27F3
  ⟳
- CLOCKWISE OPEN CIRCLE ARROW
  U+21BB
  ↻

The first does not appear in iOS 7 or 8 or 9 in either Safari or Chrome. So given that, and given [the answer by Paul D. White](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13474585/642706), I recommend using the second one, [CLOCKWISE OPEN CIRCLE ARROW](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/21BB/index.htm).

Tip: If you are a Mac user, obtain the free-of-cost app [UnicodeChecker](http://earthlingsoft.net/UnicodeChecker/). You can search for characters by name, and you can see a list of fonts (on your particular Mac) containing a glyph for that character.

## Icon Font

Some fonts have been created with scalable vector-based icons in place of regular character glyphs.

- [Font Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/), see: [fa-repeat](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/repeat)
- [Vaadin Font Icons](https://vaadin.com/font-icons/about)

Comment: ⟳ is the one that looks like the one chrome uses in it's UI.
(HTML entity `&#102270;`)

Answer (score 15):

The clockwise equivalent to your Unicode character is `&#8635;`, ↻ (although, as [David C. Bishop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187237/david-c-bishop) notes in the comments, [Chromebooks use `#27f2`, ⟳](http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_computing_symbols.html)).

<del>Using a text character is an option, but Windows XP might not display the character (depending on the character you use, and the font you display it in).</del> [@Jukka K. Korpela notes that this character is included in the Lucida Sans Unicode font, so it should work fine even in Windows XP.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13474939/20578)

As far as Wingdings fonts go, to avoid an HTTP request you’d need to be confident that the font in question in going to be installed on end user’s computers. I don’t think there’s a common cross-platform Wingdings font (I could be entirely wrong though).

You can indeed create an image from a string that contains the base64-encoded representation of the image using JavaScript. You could do so like this:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'data:image/gif;base64,' + BASE64_ENCODED_STRING; // Replace gif with whatever image format it actually is
```

The data-uri might not work great in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier though, which Windows XP users may be stuck on. (And you don’t actually need JavaScript for this: you can just put an `<img>` tag in your page with that `src` attribute.)

Comment: ⟳ ```27f2``` [is what chrome uses](http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_computing_symbols.html) for refresh.

Comment: `27f2` is ⟲ going the other way, ⟳ is `27f3`

Answer (score 14):

```css
.refresh {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<span>↻</span>
<hr>
<span class="refresh">↻</span>
```

Answer (score 10):

**Unicode 6 Character**

'CLOCKWISE DOWNWARDS AND UPWARDS OPEN CIRCLE ARROWS' (U+1F503)

Sadly font support for the glyph is not the best, so "all major browsers" might be a stretch... :-/

Comment: // , Works on Chromium and Firefox

Answer (score 3):

You mention "all major browsers", so let’s assume that:

1. not everyone have javascript
2. not everyone can embed fonts (blackberry etc)
3. not everyone supports all UNCODE representations (windows XP)
4. not everyone supports inline data uri’s (IE7-)

So what’s left? I would suggest a HTML1-compliant `IMG` element, that will also be cached after first load:

```
<img src="/refresh.gif" alt="refresh">
```

It will work in every single browser I know of, except LYNX and other pure text-based browsers. But they will show "refresh" instead, so that’s fine.

If you really want to avoid that extra 2bytes request for "modern" browsers, you can use conditional comments for IE7-:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<img src="refresh.gif" alt="refresh">
<![endif]-->
```

And something like this for the rest:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,..." alt="refresh">
```

If you’re up to something new for the newest, you can use CSS box shadows ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RFyXq/)):

```
.refresh{
    border-radius: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0),0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0),0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0),0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0),0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0),0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0),0px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0),0px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0),0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0),0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0),0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0),0px 11px rgba(0,0,0,0),0px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0),0px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0),0px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0),0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0),1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0),1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0),1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0),1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0),1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0),1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0),1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0),1px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0),1px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0),1px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0),1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0),1px 11px rgba(0,0,0,0),1px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0),1px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0),1px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0),1px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0),2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0),2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0),2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0),2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0),2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0),2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.06),2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.55),2px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.79),2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.86),2px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.86),2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.65),2px 11px rgba(0,0,0,0.31),2px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0),2px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0),2px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0),2px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0),3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0),3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0),3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0),3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0),3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.25),3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.83),3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.86),3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.83),3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.69),3px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.74),3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.86),3px 11px rgba(0,0,0,0.86),3px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),3px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.06),3px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0),3px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0),4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0),4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0),4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0),4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25),4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.83),4px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.83),4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.43),4px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0),4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0),4px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0),4px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.13),4px 11px rgba(0,0,0,0.69),4px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.86),4px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),4px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0),4px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0),5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0),5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0),5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0),5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.69),5px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.86),5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25),5px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0),5px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0),5px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0),5px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0),5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0),5px 11px rgba(0,0,0,0),5px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.69),5px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.86),5px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0.25),5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0),6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0),6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0),6px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.13),6px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.86),6px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),6px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0),6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0),6px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0),6px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0),6px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0),6px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0),6px 11px rgba(0,0,0,0),6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.13),6px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.86),6px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0.65),6px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0),7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0),7px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0),7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.43),7px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.86),7px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.31),7px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0),7px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0),7px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0),7px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0),7px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0),7px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0),7px 11px rgba(0,0,0,0),7px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0),7px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.75),7px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0.83),7px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0),8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0),8px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.43),8px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.69),8px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.86),8px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),8px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.31),8px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0),8px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0),8px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0),8px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0),8px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0),8px 11px rgba(0,0,0,0),8px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0),8px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.69),8px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0.86),8px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0),9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0),9px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.48),9px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.86),9px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.86),9px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.86),9px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.13),9px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0),9px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0),9px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0),9px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0),9px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0),9px 11px rgba(0,0,0,0),9px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0),9px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.75),9px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0.83),9px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0),10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0),10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0),10px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.79),10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.86),10px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0),10px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0),10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0),10px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0),10px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0),10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0),10px 11px rgba(0,0,0,0),10px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.13),10px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.86),10px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0.65),10px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0),11px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0),11px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0),11px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.38),11px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.83),11px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.06),11px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0),11px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0),11px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0),11px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0),11px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0),11px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0),11px 11px rgba(0,0,0,0),11px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.69),11px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.86),11px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0.25),11px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0),12px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0),12px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0),12px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0),12px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.31),12px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0),12px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0),12px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.25),12px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0),12px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0),12px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0),12px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.13),12px 11px rgba(0,0,0,0.69),12px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.86),12px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),12px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0),12px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0),13px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0),13px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0),13px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0),13px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0),13px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0),13px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.06),13px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.83),13px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.83),13px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.69),13px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.75),13px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.86),13px 11px rgba(0,0,0,0.86),13px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),13px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.06),13px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0),13px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0),14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0),14px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0),14px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0),14px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0),14px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0),14px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.13),14px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.55),14px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.79),14px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.86),14px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.86),14px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.65),14px 11px rgba(0,0,0,0.31),14px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0),14px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0),14px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0),14px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0),15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0),15px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0),15px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0),15px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0),15px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0),15px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0),15px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0),15px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0),15px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0),15px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0),15px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0),15px 11px rgba(0,0,0,0),15px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0),15px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0),15px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0),15px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the full explanation.  this is very helpful.  Is there a fallback approach that combines data URI and Unicode that would work across all major browsers?

Comment: It's funny recalling the Blackberry as a legitimate concern.

Comment: Note about your hypothesis 1: the OP clearly stated Javascript

Answer (score 1):

I think this icon will be helpful to you.

**Encodings**

```
 - HTML Entity (decimal)    &#128472;
 - HTML Entity (hex)    &#x1f5d8;
```