# XMLHttpRequest: Explicitly ENABLE browser-caching (binary data)

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, browser-cache, cache-control

**Prelude**

My Web-Application (*Keywords*: HTML, JavaScript, jQuery; *Has to work in*: IE8+, Chrome, FF) has to present live image data from a kind-of-WebCam. This "WebCam" integrates a webserver providing the live image data as `BMP`.

The image data is "downloaded" via settings the `src` attribute of an `img` tag.

**The Issue**

I want to analyze the image data client-side. To do so I'd like to pre-download the image using `XMLHttpRequest` (using [this provided stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095102/how-do-i-load-binary-image-data-using-javascript-and-xmlhttprequest/5913807#5913807)) and update the `src` attribute of the `img` tag afterwards. It is my understanding that the browser *should* then use the cached image data downloaded via `XMLHttpRequest`.

The issue is, that the browser (IE8+, FF and Chrome) issues another request to the server to download the image again (i.e. it does not use the cached data or the data is not cached in the first place).

How do I enable the browser to cache the data and to use it instead of issueing another request?

**Appendix**

The server sends a `Cache-Control: max-age=5, public` for **Chrome** and a `Cache-Control: no-store, max-age=5` for all other browsers.

In **Chrome** I am able to handle the second request by sending a `304 Not Modified`. The browser will THEN use the cached image. In all other (mentioned) browsers this does not work.

---

**Update 1**

I know, I *could* use [Data URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to update the `src` attribute. However, this wouldn't work for IE8 (see requirements above) since IE8 supports such only with 32KB max.

Comment: Im pretty sure you can use HTML5 techniques to directly draw the image instead of inserting it with `<img src="...`, then you don't have to worry about caching either.

Comment: @DanFromGermany: Thanks for the advice. Since I have to support IE8, HTML5 is not an option here. Btw, even HTML5 wouldn't solve the caching issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the issue by doing the obvious:

1. Request the image via hidden `img` (by settings `src`) **first**. That way the image gets cached by the browser.
2. Request the image binary data via AJAX **afterwards**. Since the browser then uses the above cached data, I can analyze the image data, without issueing another request.
3. Update the `src` of the "visible" image.

That way I achieve what I need: Viewing a "live" image with prior data analysis wthout having to request the image twice.